# Hiding geolocation from employer

Tags: vpn, geolocation

I have been working from remote full time for months.
Every day I connect my computer to my company network. Is there a way to hide or change my geographic location?
I mean, I would like they wouldn't know where I am.
Is a VPN enough?

Comment: Is it a company computer? Are there company management apps installed?

Comment: Yes it is a company computer...